# convert two moment objects to similar format?

Tags: momentjs, antd, react-big-calendar

I have two moment object with  one difference in format of there fields,  and that difference is the obstacle . how to convert those two objects of similar format ?
[screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXTgm.png)

the key "_i" is the difference the format of the 2nd object is working for me. So how to convert the 1st object exactly similar to 2nd object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second date is in `UTC` format.

To convert your first date to UTC format, use  [moment().utc()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) function of momentjs library.

Below is working example:

```js
var yourDate = moment().utc();

console.log(yourDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```